# Type `usize` cannot be dereferenced

Tags: types, rust, dereference

I've got some code that looks somewhat like the following:

```
let incoming: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();

match some_function(|data| {
    let temp = &mut incoming;
    Ok(*temp.write(data).unwrap())
}) {
    Ok(v) => v,
    Err(err) => return false,
};
```

Now the error I'm getting is the following:

```
error: type `usize` cannot be dereferenced
   --> src/stripe_connection.rs:127:16
     |
 127 |             Ok(*temp.write(data).unwrap())
```

For some reason I can't get my head around what I'm doing wrong, as the borrowing/lifecycle is still very new to me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you may be getting the operator precedence wrong.

`*temp.write(data).unwrap()` is equivalent to `*(temp.write(data).unwrap())`, not to `(*temp).write(data).unwrap()`. You could write the latter, but it's unnecessary, because the compiler will automatically dereference pointers in the subject of a method call (i.e. the `x` in `x.f(..)`). So you should just remove the `*` altogether here.

Comment: I've updated my question, as I tried it to remove the `*`, but that results in another error.

Comment: The Rust compiler usually will not report all errors right away; it's frequent that fixing an error makes other errors start appearing. Try to figure out how to fix the new errors, and if you still can't figure it out, please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 5):

[`usize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html) doesn't implement the [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) trait, so you can't apply `*` to it. `write()` returns a `Result<usize>`, so when you `unwrap()` it and apply the dereferencing asterisk:

```
*temp.write(data).unwrap()
```

You are attempting to do

```
*usize
```

Which is not possible.